# Mathematica HELP with While and Module command

Tags: loops, wolfram-mathematica

Does this equation work for all sequences `f[n]`?

```
f[n_] :=  Module[{x = intial value, y = 0, i = 0},

            While[i++ < n, {x, y} = {y, equation}]; y]
```

Specifically, I'm looking at the equation `6*n*f[n]=f[n-1]+n!` with initial condition `f[0] = 7`. But, I'd like the solution to general, so that I can apply it to other equations. And, I'd like to use `Module` and `While`.

thank you.

Comment: Yes, it does. I mean no, definitely not. That is to say, what is it you are asking? I cannot make sense of the above in any programming language I know (which would include Mathematica, on a good day at least). At a minumun: What is 'equation', and is n guaranteed to be a nonnegative value?

Comment: Sure that will work. Syntatically there's nothing wrong with that actually. I'll guarantee you that it won't do what you want though.

Comment: @Daniel i meant 'formula' in a way and yeah n > 0

Comment: @ Mike im trying to implement this sequence using the method shown above .....'6*n*f[n]=f[n-1]+n!' for f[0] = 7 and n>0  .....

Comment: @Sunday, with that additional info, I've edited your question. Also, it is preferred if you write in complete sentences and do not shorten words, e.g. thnx, but contractions are fine. By doing that you deviate from accepted English grammar which may make it difficult for a non-native speaker to read it.

Comment: Sunday, I don't understand your requirement for `Module` and `While`.  The code you posted above, give or take, is what I gave you in reply to a previous question, because it fit your requirements.  However, unless you have an academic need for something else, the methods that Michael Pilat gives below are more expressive and versatile.

Answer (score 7):

The cleanest and most common way to implement a recurring sequence is to just define `f` using [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), "remembering" terms as they are computed for efficiency:

```
f[0] = 7
f[n_Integer?Positive] := f[n] = (f[n - 1] + n!)/(6 n)
```

Then:

```
In[29]:= Table[f[n], {n, 0, 6}]

Out[29]= {7, 4/3, 5/18, 113/324, 7889/7776, 941009/233280, 168902609/8398080}
```

If you're not required to program the recurrence yourself, you could also use [`RecurrenceTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) to generate terms directly without defining `f`:

```
In[30]:= RecurrenceTable[{a[0] == 7, 6 n a[n] == a[n - 1] + n!}, a, {n, 6}]

Out[30]= {7, 4/3, 5/18, 113/324, 7889/7776, 941009/233280, 168902609/8398080}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to calculate the sequence:

```
f(n) = (f(n-1) + n!) / (6 * n)
```

One way to implement it is:

```
f[n_] := Module[{values},
       values = Table[0, {n}];
       values[[1]] = 7;
       Do[values[[i]] = (values[[i-1]] + (i-1)!) / (6 * (i-1)), {i, 2, n}]
       values];
```

Or equivalently:

```
f[n_] := Module[{values, i = 2},
       values = Table[0, {n}];
       values[[1]] = 7;
       While[i <= n, values[[i]] = (values[[i-1]] + (i-1)!) / (6 * (i-1)); i++];
       values];
```

There are much more efficient ways though.

I forget the differences of Bock and Module off hand, but they're very similar.

Comment: Buh i'm trying to use module and while commands cause they take less time to compute

Comment: @Sunday: Do loops are usually faster than While and For loops. Check my answer for the equivalent While loop.

Comment: Shudnt the output be this whereas urs gives both formulae give something else {4/3, 5/18, 113/324, 7889/7776, 941009/233280, 168902609/8398080, \
42495225809/352719360, 14264139821009/16930529280, \
6158014604947409/914248581120, 3323783265773203409/54854914867200}

Comment: Can you do it this way------> fib[n_] := 
 Module[{x = 7, y = 0, i = 0}, 
  While[i++ < n, {x, y} = {y, ((x + n!)/(6 n))}]; y]

Comment: @Sunday, might I ask what information do you have to show that `Module` and `While` are the fastest, as [Michael Pilat's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546229/mathematica-help-with-while-and-module-command/5546750#5546750) solution will be very fast?

Comment: After the first iteration, `y` (0) is assigned to `x`, and then is used as `f[n-1]` in the next iteration, but that isn't what you want.